# jQuery animate left not working

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a simple jQuery animate, when you click on a div called "second_image" the whole "image_holder" div (which holds the second_image) moves to the left. I'm trying to do this with the .animate command but for some reason it's not working.

Below is my complete jQuery - you will notice that the div "second_image" is appended to an existing div...is this what is causing the issue?

```
$('.gallery').click(function () {
    $('#images_holder').remove();

    $('#overlay').fadeIn().append('<div id="images_holder"><div class="main_image"></div><div class="second_image"></div></div>');
    $main_img_url = $(this).attr('data-first-img-url');
    $second_img_url = $(this).attr('data-second-img-url');

    $('.main_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $main_img_url + "')");
    $('.second_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $second_img_url + "')");
});

$('.second_image').click(function () {
    $('#images_holder').animate({
        left: "+=270px"
    });
});

$(".close_gallery").click(function () {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();

});
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

jSfiddle here (press escape to exit the pop-up mode) http://jsfiddle.net/9d9sz/6/

Comment: Do you want the image to keep moving left on every new click over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're binding a click event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

You create the 'second_image' div only when you click on `.gallery`, so when you're `$('.second_image').click` runs, there is no element to bind the click too.

Try changing your code to this:

```
$('.gallery').click(function () {
  $('#images_holder').remove();

  $('#overlay').fadeIn().append('<div id="images_holder"><div class="main_image"></div><div class="second_image"></div></div>');
  $main_img_url = $(this).attr('data-first-img-url');
  $second_img_url = $(this).attr('data-second-img-url');

  $('.main_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $main_img_url + "')");
  $('.second_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $second_img_url + "')");

  $('.second_image').click(function () {
    $('#images_holder').animate({
      left: "+=270px"
    });
  });
});

$(".close_gallery").click(function () {
  $('#overlay').fadeOut();

});
```

That way you're binding a click event to `.second_image` after it's been created.

Comment: That's a terrible suggestion. Every time someone clicks on `.gallery` - an event listener gets bound to `.second_image` which could result in multiple listeners being bounds.

Comment: @Adam - agreed - but this code was hardly using "best practices" from the beginning. I just answered why the click wasn't working - not completely rewriting their code.

Comment: Yeah, not the best approach... Apart from it, if you keep clicking on the `second_image` it will keep moving left, which I believe is not what he is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `270px`:

```
$('#images_holder').animate({
    left:"270px"
});
```

Also, you need to use delegation as you are adding an event to a dynamically created element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.second_image', function () {
    $('#images_holder').animate({
        left: "270px"
    });
});
```

Notice that you need to add delegation also to other events as the `close_gallery`.

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/9d9sz/9/

Answer (score 0):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/9d9sz/12/)**

Try this

Add the below code inside the  `$('.gallery').click(function() {`

```
$('.second_image').click(function() {
        $('#images_holder').animate({
        left:"270px"
          });
        });
```

This element doesnot exist on page load, Its dynamically created on `$('.gallery').click()`, so the binding of the click event only works after the element is created

### Or

creating a Delegate event instead

### Working **[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/9d9sz/11/)**

```
$(document).on('click','.second_image',function() {
    $('#images_holder').animate({
    left:"270px"
      });
    });
```